# PayPal Subscription Email

Tags: paypal, subscription

I've setup a subscription on my site. Everything is working fine regarding money being deposited and our fulfillment warehouse is located when a new customer enrolls. The problem is that the PayPal only sends the Transaction Details (amount and address) and not the Subscription Details (the actual products ordered).

Looking under My Account > Overview, I can see that these are two different invoices. How can I send the warehouse the Subscription Details instead of (or in addition to) the Transaction details?

If there isn't a way to send the Subscription details, is there another way to add the item name to the Transaction details?

EDIT:

This is the button.

```
<div class="hide autoship_form" id="location_can_5">
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions" type="hidden">
<input name="business" value="DVU25CHPLXZ2S" type="hidden">
<input name="lc" value="can" type="hidden">
<input name="item_name" value="Autoship within Canada" type="hidden">
<input name="item_number" value="CAN" type="hidden">
<input name="no_note" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="no_shipping" value="2" type="hidden">
<input name="rm" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="return" value="http://domain.com/autoship.php" type="hidden">
<input name="cancel_return" value="http://domain.com/autoship.php" type="hidden">
<input name="src" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="currency_code" value="USD" type="hidden">
<input name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribe_LG.gif:NonHosted" type="hidden">
<table>
<tbody><tr><td><input name="on0" value="Monthly Autoship" type="hidden"></td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
<option name="item_name" value="1 Pro">1 Pro: $82.54</option>
<option name="item_name" value="2 Pro">2 Pro: $148.69</option>
<option name="item_name" value="3 Pro">3 Pro: $216.97</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<input name="currency_code" value="USD" type="hidden">
<input name="option_select0" value="1 Pro" type="hidden">
<input name="option_amount0" value="82.54" type="hidden">
<input name="option_period0" value="M" type="hidden">
<input name="option_frequency0" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="option_select1" value="2 Pro" type="hidden">
<input name="option_amount1" value="148.69" type="hidden">
<input name="option_period1" value="M" type="hidden">
<input name="option_frequency1" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="option_select2" value="3 Pro" type="hidden">
<input name="option_amount2" value="216.97" type="hidden">
<input name="option_period2" value="M" type="hidden">
<input name="option_frequency2" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="option_index" value="0" type="hidden">
<input name="notify_url" value="http://www.domain.com/affiliate/plugins/PayPal/paypal.php" type="hidden">
<input name="custom" value="" id="apa_5s2cv8xd" type="hidden">
<br>
<input src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="" border="0" type="image">
<img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" border="0" height="1" width="1">
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How is PayPal sending you the details?  What method are you using to get the details?  I would suggest using IPN, if you are already not usnig this.  IPN will send all the details regarding the transaction/profile.  Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that notifies you of events related to PayPal transactions. You can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, such as fulfilling orders, tracking customers, and providing status and other information related to a transaction.

You can find more on IPN [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro).  Once on that page, there are also some more links on the left hand side of that page, that include sample scripts, setup, and what variables get returned.

You could have your IPN script send the information that you are needing to 
your fullfillment warehouse, and automate the whole process.

Comment: I've edited the post to show the button. The "<input name="item_name" value="Autoship within Canada" type="hidden">" value gets passed here, but not the value on the selection options.

Comment: Thanks for responding Chad. Looking at the IPN was just confusing and I don't think it could work for this setup. The site is replicated for each of our members, so every person that signs up to the site, has their own autoship page to send their customers to. (We track the purchasing URL to give the owner commission) The "listener" for the IPN would have to talk to multiple pages that are generated on signup.